# Do I have enough time to perform a Server update when my App is started from Background mode?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, core-location, background-process

I am failing to find any documentation on this. If my application is able to use background location services, how much processing can it really do before the device stops the task as its using too much resource?

E.g. When the location changes, I would like to ping my server with the new location.

Regards:

John

Comment: The title you have choose is totally incorrect. You are obviously asking a totally different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an app has the permission of getting location updates in the background, then you are not limited on performing any tasks, so you could run any code, as the app is allowed to execute code while it is suspended (this is used by apps providing navigation).
However, be aware, that Apple will not approve your App, with the background Location updates permission, unless it's an App that would justify this requirement (Sports tracking App, Navigation App, etc)

You can get location updates from Region Monitoring or Significant Location changes, without having to use the location updates background mode.

So now comes the tricky part. Do I have enough time to perform a Server update of the users Location when my App is started from Background mode by the Region Monitoring or Significant Location services ?

The answer, **seems to be yes**, [as suggested by this article](http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/)

I haven't tried this, but judging by the code, I don't find a reason why this shouldn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare App’s Supported Background Tasks in info.plist

Under the information property list add array given format below:

Inforrmation Property list (Dictionary)  ->
  Required background modes         (array)         (1 item)  ->
    item 0                         (String) -        App registers for location updates

after these settings in info.plist you can do code which you want to do in background process at AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;

```
[_locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

For more information you can visit:

[Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)